# egrep command with piped variable in ssh throwing No Such File or Directory error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

Ok, here I'm again, struggling with ssh. I'm trying to retrieve some data from remote log file based on tokens. I'm trying to pass multiple tokens in egrep command via ssh:

```
IFS=$'\n'
commentsArray=($(ssh $sourceUser@$sourceHost "$(egrep "$v" /$INSTALL_DIR/$PROP_BUNDLE.log)"))
echo ${commentsArray[0]}
echo ${commentsArray[1]}
commax=${#commentsArray[@]}
echo $commax
```

where $v is something like below but it's length is dynamic. Meaning it can have many file names seperated by pipe.

```
UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-22--07:05:37.jar|UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-22--07:03:57.jar
```

The output which I get is:

```
oracle@172.18.12.42's password:
bash: UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-22--07:03:57.jar/New: No such file or directory
bash: line 1: UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-22--07:05:37.jar/nouserinput: No such file or directory


0
```

Thing worth noting is that my log file data has spaces in it. So, in the code piece I've given, the actual comments which I want to extract start after the jar file name like : *UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-22--07:03:57.jar/*

The actual comments are 'New Life Starts here' but the logs show that we are actually getting it till 'New' and then it breaks at space. I tried giving IFS but of no use. Probably I need to give it on remote but I don't know how should I do that.
Any help?

Comment: Is `$v` supposed to be a regex with two alternatives, or a literal string? But that's not your problem. The real problem is that the regex pipe is unquoted by the time it's sent to the remote shell so it's interpreted as a shell pipe.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Thanks Jim for pointing that out. So, what should be the workaround....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is trying to run the `egrep "$v" /$INSTALL_DIR/$PROP_BUNDLE.log` on the local machine, and pass the result of that as the command to run via SSH.

I suspect that you meant for that command to be run on the remote machine. Remove the inner `$()` to get that to happen (and fix the quoting):

```
commentsArray=($(ssh $sourceUser@$sourceHost "egrep '$v' '/$INSTALL_DIR/$PROP_BUNDLE.log'"))
```

Comment: Well, I tried it but this did not solve the problem. The error I got was: `egrep: \\home\<path>\propagateBundle.log: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Adi That doesn't look right; you used backslashes in that error, but Linux/Unix uses forward slashes to separate paths. Can you please post the actual definitions of `$INSTALL_DIR` and `$PROP_BUNDLE`, as well as the result of sshing to the target machine (or one of them if there's more than one) and running the command manually on one of the log file (including the command that you ran)?

Comment: Error:`egrep: //home/oracle/Oracle/Knowledge/Search/propagateBundle.log: No such file or directory` INSTALL_DIR: `/home/oracle/Oracle/Knowledge/Search` PROP_BUNDLE: `propagateBundle`  I'm sorry, that was a typo from my side

Comment: After I ssh, it asks for a password and then trow this error. Please note that I'm doing ssh twice  for the same remote. First ssh is  fetching correct results. I'm manipulating that result and again sending it via ssh to the same remote. Running grep command directly on the terminal of remote fetches proper results.

Comment: @Adi Can you please show exactly what happens when you SSH into the remote and run the command directly from the terminal? It will be easier for you to edit it directly into your question, rather than putting the result in a comment. Can you also edit it to include the exact new version of the script, as I suggested that you modify it?

Comment: hey man, it worked!!!! I was missing a quote, my mistake. t worked like charm!! Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fgrep` to avoid regex special interpretation from your input:

```
commentsArray=($(ssh $sourceUser@$sourceHost "$(fgrep "$v" /$INSTALL_DIR/$PROP_BUNDLE.log)"))
```

Comment: I tried this anubhava, but it completely froze my script. It first asked for mthe password because of ssh. As I keyed in the password, script completely froze whereas it earlier was giving error at this point. I waited for long to see for any response. The file it's searching in is a very small file of about 50 lines currently.

Comment: That must be due to your ssh connection since fgrep is anyday faster than egrep.

Comment: Well, I'm doing ssh twice that connects to the same machine. The first ssh extracts some data, that data is manipulated and again sent to the same remote machine to extract data from log files. The first ssh is working fine. fgrep is in the second ssh, which doesn't work. egrep is returning some results and then showing error while fgrep doesn't return anything. So, concisely, first ssh on the remote is working while second ssh for the same remote machine is extracting data but with error by using egrep and feeze the script if done with fgrep.

Comment: Ok try `grep -F` "$v"` instead of `fgrep`

Comment: did the change but it still freezes in the same way

Comment: First ssh login to remote sever and try executing this `grep -F` command there and see if that works.